# Website loading on some networks, but not on others

Tags: networking, dns, linode

I am having an issue understanding the problem of why my site will load on some networks, but not others.

I am getting "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" on Chrome in the following environments:

1) Office Network - This made me believe that it was a firewall issue

2) Open WiFi Network at a Coffee Shop - This made me believe that it was not a firewall issue

I am able to access the site without any issues from my home network and also when turning my phone into a hotspot.

I did some digging and was hopeful that adding an IPv6 record to my DNS would have resolved the issue(Maybe those networks were pulling from IPv6) but that also did not resolve the issue.

I ended up running a test on MXToolBox.com and received these warnings back.

MXToolBox Response

[image: MXToolBox Response]

I do not have any email setup with this domain so I am not concerned about the email record errors, but the one I can't figure out is the top one with Category: DNS and the message of "DNS Record not found". The "More Info" link says "We did not find a DNS record at the location specified. You should check with DNS provider to ensure the record has been published and there are no typos."

I have an A record pointing to the correct IP(As I am able to access it from my home and cell phone networks). I added an AAAA record for IPv6(Though not sure I fully understand why it's necessary). My A record has been added for several weeks now, so it's not a propagation issue and my AAAA record was added a few days ago with a SOA of 10 minutes, so do not believe it to be a propagation issue either.

I have opened this question because I'm not even sure how to google this any further as everything returned back is typically client side(Clear your cache/cookies) and not what my issue is.

My VPS is hosted by Linode.

Thanks in advance for any advice/help.

Comment: The error is about name resolution, nothing you will do in your browser (clearing cache or cookies) can change this problem.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickMevzek. I realize that client side doesn't resolve this issue, but do you know if it's a DNS setting or something else that can resolve this?